# What is the best way to plot a spectrogram with openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, spectrogram

I have written a code to calculate the spectrogram of a sine & cos signals, applied the Hann Window, calculated FFT, Calculated log magnitude of frequency coefficients.

I tested that it is all working by writing a simple function in openGL to plot a magnitude-frequency spectrum and I got the following results:

[image]

As you can see, there are 2 bars which indicates the sine * cos waves.

I have all the information I need to plot a [spectrogram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Spectrogram-19thC.png) (frequencies,magnitude,time)
Now my question is how can I draw that? my first thought was to draw dots, so I'll use the time array for the interval time I need to draw the dots on the X axie, frequencies array to where to draw them on the Y axis, and the magnitude would be the color of the dot.

Maybe that's an inefficient idea because I saw that drawing dots is really inefficient in openGL so I don't know what's a better idea, I couldn't find any "simple" examples of openGL spectrogram online.

Comment: Make an array of colors, fill it once, then give it to GL as a texture.

Comment: 2d array? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Yep, a 2d array.

Comment: oh so instead of doing what I said which is drawing every dot individually I just put it in that array and give GL that as a texture?

Comment: why not try using framebuffer for it let the given equation to plot be y=f(x) now just check if it satisfies. and if it does then out a colored pixel else color the fragment black. and after that apply maybe a spread shader to get thicker line.!?

Comment: Are you using <V3 openGL? I am asking because with VBO and shaders, drawing dots or lines should not be slow at all.

Comment: I'm using glew-1.11.0 because I couldn't find another version which include the "include" and "lib" folders @AdrianMaire

Comment: you should have access to OpenGL 4.5 with glew-1.11. So you are **not** using glVertex and such right?

Comment: nope @AdrianMaire

Comment: why not pass the FFT result as texture and compute the dots (you wanted in first place) inside Fragment shader? They are ideal for this.

Answer (score 0):

@HolyBlackCat comment is the answer

*"Make an array of colors, fill it once, then give it to GL as a texture"*